# " '$' is null or not an object " error in ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending  the ajax request to the tomcat server and getting response as ,

```
function getAgentName(){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "agentName.html",

        success: function(response){
            // we have the response 

            if(response != null && response !="" && response !="null"){
                alert( "response  :"+$.trim(response)); // line 10
            }

        },  
        error: function(e){  
            alert('Error: ' + e);  
        }, 
        complete:function(){
            getAgentName();
        }
    }); 
}
```

I got the error in response success `alert` in the `line 10` as  `'$' is null or not an object`  .

**Edit :** I have already added the `Jquery 1.9.1.js`.

Don't know how to solve this. Hope our stack users will help me .

Comment: Is it definitely that line and not the $.ajax line?

Comment: From what you're describing, the only way that could happen is if you're actually killing off `$` after this call is made, before the AJAX call returns. Maybe something like `$ = null;`.

Comment: It is the response alert line only.

Comment: You will need to provide the general context in which `getAgentName()` is called.

Comment: This fiddle use your exactly code and it works fine. There must be some code somewhere else causing this. http://jsfiddle.net/8eTzd/

Comment: Have you tried `jquery.trim(response)`? And have you tried `console.debug(response)` (I guess response will hold an object and trim expects and returns a string)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the link to your JQuery library might be wrong. Check if you included the right one.

Here is the latest hosted by jQuery: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Comment: If jQuery isn't included, how does he get an error in the success callback of the ajax call?

Comment: @Archer: Its possible the OP made a mistake in where the error was occurring. This seems more likely than something making $ not be defined there when it was earlier in the code...

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite a chance that there's error in response. But just to give it a proper shot, instead of using

```
$.trim(response)
```

use

```
response.trim()
```

If you're still getting issue, then it's a response related issue, else you've already solved your problem.

Comment: Totally wrong. I've update Wayne's Fiddle above and clearly trim() can work with jQuery without any issue. Heck in fact any JS function will work without a single issue.
 See it here http://jsfiddle.net/8eTzd/2/